# form submission odoo template odoo

Tags: html, python-2.7, controller, odoo

I am confused in performing form submission from template HTML code.

My controller is defined as below:

```
@http.route('/verify/product', auth='public', methods=['POST'])
def verify(self, **kw):
    value = po
    return request.render('test.main',{})
```

My Template is:

```
<template id='sub'>
   <form action="/verify/product" method="POST">
     Enter Number : <input type="text" name="po">
     <button name="submit" type="submit" > Submit </button>
   </form>
</template>
```

I get following error:

> Not Found Page ( 404)

Answer (score -1):

You need call id of template.
In your case :

```
return request.render('test.sub',{})
```

test: y